# strange visual behavior on maximized qml window

Tags: qt, qml

I've got a qml based application which renders fine as long as it is not maximized. The error occurs to different extend on different platforms and on resizing/unmaximizing the window everything goes back to normal. On linux it looks like the window freezed but if you resize it you will see that e.g. previous button clicking indeed triggered something but no visual update was shown during that time. On windows (7), updates and reacting to user input is shown but there are a lot of artifacts duplicating the state before the window was maximized that wont disappear until resizing, so a portion of the window is not refreshed here too

Does somebody have any idea by what may cause this behavior? **Can I - in the worstcase - disable that the window can be maximized?**

Edit:
I tested it with a minimal qt quick controls 2 template application again without modification and i have the same behavior (tested on ubuntu)

The example I used is quite simple and still the issue is still present:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page1 {
        }

        Page {
            Label {
                text: qsTr("Second page")
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("First")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Second")
        }
    }
}
```

Its the simple template from New Project > Applications > Qt Quick Controls 2 Application in Qt Creator. I tested it with Qt 5.9.1 and 5.10.0

Maybe a general qt problem in conjuction with graphics drivers?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: In Arch Linux with Qt 5.10.1 your code works correctly.

Comment: the behavior occurs not each time when maximizing btw. Only like each 4th-6th time when maximizing